# How to call @Html.Action through Ajax in MVC (.NET)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, loader

I have a View which renders an action. For example:

```
<h1>Test View</h1>
@Html.Action("Intro", "Account", new { id = "5" })
```

However, this Action takes 10-20 seconds to load.

How can i wrap it in an ajax with a loader?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a DIV to serve as a placeholder, then load the content on document load event into the DIV. You can also add a GIF image to show progress and hide it when the content is loaded, Here's an example of how to do it:

```
<h1>Test View</h1>
<div id="accountInfo"></div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Html.Url("Intro", "Account")',
         dataType: "html",
         data: { id : 5 },

         success: function (content) {
            $("#accountInfo").html(content);
         },
         error: function (e) { }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Please note I didn't test that and just wrote it from the top of my head so there might be some minor syntax errors but this gives you the main idea.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just helping if anyone runs across this, the 'url' needs quotes. 
For example:

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "@urlStr",
         dataType: "html",
         data: { id : 5 },
         success: function (content) {
            $("#accountInfo").html(content);
         },
         error: function (e) { }
      });
   });
</script>

Comment: I recommend to add ```async: true``` to ajax request.